# Chat button still showing on Meta questions

Tags: support, status-norepro, chat

Under each question, at least for me, next to the flag button there's still a chat button that's supposed to link to a chatroom for a specific question. However, the three-day beta has ended and that link now redirects to the thanks page.

Answer (score 6):

Can you take off the grease-monkey script? We didn't change the parent site, except via grease-monkey.

Comment: Then why is there a Cornify button on everything? Now I am angry and will cover up your answer with unicorns and rainbows. Take that! And that! And that!

Comment: @mmyers - no stop! I can't see the desktop! no more!

Comment: I never installed a Greasemonkey script, I'm using Chrome but my extensions have been broken for a long time. Odd.